# setting git insteadof in command line

Tags: git

Because of the poor network connection. I built some git repository mirrors to open source software.

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig

[url "git://127.0.0.1/chromiumos"]
    insteadOf = "https://chromium.googlesource.com"
[url "git://127.0.0.1/chromiumos"]
    insteadOf = "https://boringssl.googlesource.com"
[url "git://127.0.0.1/chromiumos"]
    insteadOf = "https://pdfium.googlesource.com"
[url "git://127.0.0.1/chromiumos"]
    insteadOf = "https://weave.googlesource.com"
```

I want to made such configuration by typing command line, so remove them first:

```
git config --global --unset url.git://127.0.0.1/chromiumos.insteadof
```

Then add them again:

```
git config --global url.git://127.0.0.1/chromiumos.insteadof https://boringssl.googlesource.com
git config --global url.git://127.0.0.1/chromiumos.insteadof https://chromium.googlesource.com
git config --global url.git://127.0.0.1/chromiumos.insteadof https://pdfium.googlesource.com
git config --global url.git://127.0.0.1/chromiumos.insteadof https://weave.googlesource.com
```

But the result is not what I expected, only one config is take effect:

```
$ git config -global -l

url.git://127.0.0.1/chromiumos.insteadof=https://weave.googlesource.com
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As noted in [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> Multiple lines can be added to an option by using the --add option.

That is, after setting the first one, you need `--add` for the remainder so that they do not simply replace the first.  (You can use `--add` on the first one too, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`git config --global --add url.{URL}.insteadOf {URL}`

where `{URL}` is your url